# Otimizar 20 Milhões de registro banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Código Create:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tb_empresas_ativas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cpf` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome_cliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `razao_social` varchar(355) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome_fantasia` varchar(355) DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacao` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_situacao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `motivo_situa` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_natureza_juridica` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_inicio_atividade` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_registro` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_insert` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `indexid` (`id`,`cpf`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35085341 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Tenho uma tabela cliente no mysql com 20 milhões de registros. Quando eu vou contar quantos clientes por estado, por cidade ou até mesmo consultar um unico cpf a consulta demora muito. Segue o schema da tabela, lembrando que ja está com índice. Será que se eu transformar essa tabela uma pra muitos resolveria o problema ?!

```
id                int(11)
cpf               varchar(255)
nome_cliente      varchar(255)
razao_social      varchar(355)
nome_fantasia     varchar(355)
situacao          int(11)
data_situacao     varchar(255)
motivo_situa      int(11)
cod_nat_jurid     int(11)
data_in_ativ      varchar(255)
tipo_registro     varchar(255)
data_insert       timestamp
```

Ou alguma outra ideia de como eu posso otimizar a consulta desses dados ? A mudança de banco de dados também é viável e teria como fazer. Mongodb, sqlserver...

Estou usando php7 e mysql versão 5. Obrigado desde já :)

Comment: Quais são as queries que são feitas (e que estão demorando)? Quais estão com índice (acho que seria conveniente postar o código do CREATE, já que ele diz o index)? Quando executa um `EXPLAIN` e um `SHOW PROFILE` (e `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING`) quais são os resultados?

Comment: @Inkeliz Postei o código do create. Ex: SELECT cpf, nome_cliente FROM tb_empresas_ativas WHERE cpf = '00008784884' ja é uma query que fica lenta.

Comment: Qual o sentido deste campo com este tamanho? Ou cpf não tem a conotação atual e amplamente utilizada pelos brasileiros? Não entendi `nome_cliente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, se é um nome porque int? Idem data_situação, etc.

Comment: Postei o create da tabela errado, vou editar aqui.

Comment: Talvez o problema seja a ordem do `UNIQUE`, já que está executando somente com `cpf`. Eu testaria duas coisas: altera a ordem de `UNIQUE KEY \`indexid\` (\`id\`,\`cpf\`)` para `UNIQUE KEY \`indexid\` (\`cpf\`, \`id\`)` ou cria um novo index somente para o `cpf`, _o`id` já tem o index do PK_.

Comment: Só se deve criar índices para agilizar consultas frequentes, algumas consultas vão demorar , uma  solução pode ser criar tabelas consolidadas e carregaá-las em hora ociosa de máquina. Que índices as tabelas tem ? Que tipo de consultas são feitas ? Com que frequência ? Pq cpf é varchar(255) cnpj vai até 14 sem edição.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode particionar as tabelas horizontalmente, isso consiste em devidir as tabela por índices, por exemplo a data, cpf, id. Assim irão existir várias tabelas subdivididas pelo índice diminuindo o tempo de consulta. Não sei o processo completo para o particionamento porém já mechi com isso, então vou deixar alguns links.

Sobre a partição de tabelas:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017

Uma interface que usei muito para partição, se chama Citus:
https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v8.2/

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Vinicius vou dar uma lida nesse cara :)